# Trouble reproducing keras neural network with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

> Edits below

I am in the process of learning about artificial neural networks using the Keras library and in order to ensure that I have a good understanding of the basics of neural network classification, I have been trying to reproduce a neural network written with Keras using only tensorflow. However, I have run into some problems.

```
training_epochs = 100
n_input = 11
n_hidden_1 = 6
n_hidden_2 = 6
n_output = 1

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=n_hidden_1, init='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=n_input))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=n_hidden_2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=n_output, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=training_epochs)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
```

So essentially I am using a neural network with 2 hidden layers of size 6, an input layer of size 11, and an output of size 1. My output uses the sigmoid function to generate probabilities in order to classify training data into binary categories. I tried to reproduce this with tensorflow as follows:

```
 training_epochs = 100
 n_input = 11
 n_hidden_1 = 6
 n_hidden_2 = 6
 n_output = 1

 def neuralNetwork(x, weights):
    layer_1 = tf.matmul(x, weights['h1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    output_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['output'])
    return output_layer

 weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_hidden_2, n_output]))
}

 x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_input]) # [?, 11]
 y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_output]) # [?, 1]

 logits = neuralNetwork(x, weights)
 prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

 cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y))
 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
 with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        loss, accuracy = session.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x:X_train, y:y_train})
        print('Epoch: {} Acc: {}'.format(epoch+1, accuracy))
    print('Model has completed training.')
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Cannot feed value of shape (8000,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)
```

My input data has 8000 rows with 11 columns and my output data has 8000 rows and 1 column. In order to try to reshape my data, I tried feeding it in row by row, but I kept getting more errors. Am I going about this the right way? Any help would be appreciated!

> Edit: So I updated my code following the given suggestions. I am now getting output for accuracy, however, it seems to finish at around 4-5%. Furthermore, the accuracy also seems to decrease over time rather than improving. When I increase the number of training epochs to 200, the accuracy dips even lower (to around 2%).

```
Epoch: 1 Acc: 7.641509056091309
...
...
Epoch: 100 Acc: 4.339457035064697
```

Comment: If you have 800 samples, where does 8000 come from? It seems, regardless of this, that you just need to have y with the same shape of the placeholder: `y_train=y_train.reshape((-1,1))`

Comment: @DanielMöller I'm sorry, it was a typo (should be 8000). I updated the relevant line and my question after taking your suggestion.

Comment: also note that you are using random uniform weights in Keras and random normal weights in Tf

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for the catch, I fixed it to match (same problem remains though)

Comment: I'm not used to tensorflow, but I don't see anywhere anything that defines the weights as actually weights. Biases are also missing. And softmax is different from sigmoid.

Comment: @DanielMöller changed to sigmoid and my accuracy now hovers around 5%. With regards to the weights, I implemented them the same way when solving the mnist example problem and my network functioned correctly so I'm not sure that is the problem

Comment: Is `tf.Variable` automatically an adjustable weight?

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes `tf.Variable` takes an initial value and is trained/adjusted over time

Comment: After further inspection, the problem is most likely the line loss, accuracy = session.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x:X_train, y:y_train}). You use the optimizer output as loss and the cost as accuracy. Try using just session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=...) in the loop and you should get reasonable results.